# lightning:inputRichText issue in salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, inputrichtext

I am using `lightning:inputRichText` in aura component which is working fine in lightning experience, but when I open the same app in Salesforce1 in my iphone I am not able to type anything in text area. I also tried `ui:inputRichText` with same device, but this time everything is working fine as expected. I know `lightning:inputRichText` is still in Beta. Can anyone face the same problem or any solution for this issue.

I simply used: `<lightning:inputRichText value="" />` in my component and open it in saleaforce1 in iPhone. It is working fine with Android.